# How can I avoid POW attacks?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I was playing Mario Kart Wii, and doing really well in the races, until someone caught me with a POW powerup.

Is there any way to avoid spinning out when the POW gets used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you shake the controller at the right time (just as the last shake comes to spin you out) you won't lose speed,  but you'll still spin and lose your shells and mushrooms (or whatever other item you may have had).

If you are in the air after a jump from a ramp you won't get hit at all.

Comment: By jump, I assume you mean off of a ramp and not just the tiny hops you can normally do?

Comment: @JeffMercado yeah of a ramp, I'll clarify

Answer (score -1):

Manuel: Hit the B button (ZR if pro controller) to hop into the air, then you will see a blue circle below your kart or bike.

Automatic:  You cannot dodge it.

You can jump off a ramp to dodge it, but it isn't good to rely on that because there may not be a nearby ramp when your about to get hit.